# How to know Eclipse runtime classpath?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

I am a big fan of Eclipse, but now, there is an issue bother me.

My college is using IntelliJ to run our Sprint Boot application (just a main function). The IntelliJ will print the runtime classpath in console.

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Duser.language=zh -Duser.region=CN -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -noverify -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=57342 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain -Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true "-javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=57343:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jaccess...
```

Does eclipse has the similar feature? How should I know what classpath and other JVM parameters are using during the Java Application run?

Comment: I want to know also, any reference?

Answer (score -1):

Check your runtime classpath by going to Run -> Run Configurations and select your application configuration. Check the classpath setting there.

There is another workaround for this also. Eclipse by default will include your output folder (usually named bin) in your classpath. Typically anything that are not compilable in src folder will be copied to bin as is. I assumed your property file is not located in src folder. What you can do is to open your project property and add the folder where your property is located into Java Buld Path -> Source (tab). This way eclipse will copy the content of that folder into bin and will be in the classpath.

Comment: what do you suggest is the classpath pof a Project, not the classpath of eclipse itself. And the secondone is what op want to know if i understand the question correctly

Comment: I want to know the Java App running classpath :) . But the answer is not what I want. I know how to configure src folder. But the classpath of Java App running in the Eclipse is not always like the answer mentioned. For example, in the maven project, the test source should be ignored. In the IntelliJ, the classpath will be printed out, but Eclipse not.